# section __TEXT/__text address out of range file framework for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, x86-64

My geth.framework working past Xcode 13.3 well but New Xcode version is 14.3 is not working and got this every time so anyone idea about this so Please let me know?

**in /Users/Live Project/Brewary App/Pods/Geth/Frameworks/Geth.framework/Geth(go.o), section __TEXT/__text address out of range file '/Users/Live Project/Brewary App/Pods/Geth/Frameworks/Geth.framework/Geth' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

**Question :** Anyone idea about this error ?

Comment: Could you resolve it? I'm facing same issue.

Comment: Still not at solve but i have replace new library

Comment: what library are you using now?

Comment: @ShikhaSharma I m using this https://github.com/web3swift-team/web3swift library